# The way to write <a href=""> on Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I haven't used `Django` for a while, so I forgot many things of `Django`. When I click url link on [this site](https://bananaman.herokuapp.com/), it moves to another pages, but the pages don't work properly. But if I reload the page or retype the same url, the pages work.

I wrote like these,

```
<a href="{% url 'slideup_like_magic' %}">slideUp header</a>
```

or

```
<a href="/carousel/">carousel</a>
```

I read several pages, but I don't know what to do. Would you please help me?

index.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-EN">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">  <!-- for IE --> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"> 
    <title>Welcome to my Samples!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span>Welcome to my samples!!</span>
        <dl>
            <dt>Bootstrap</dt>
            <dd><a href="{% url 'affix' %}">affix</a></dd>
            <dd><a href="/carousel/">carousel</a></dd>
            <dt>BxSlider</dt>
            <dd><a href="/bxslider/">responsive</a></dd>
            <dt>Magic</dt>
            <dd><a href="{% url 'slideup_like_magic' %}">slideUp header</a></dd>
        </dl>
    </div>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

import hello.views

# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'gettingstarted.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', hello.views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^bxslider/$', hello.views.bxslider, name='bxslider'),
    url(r'^affix/$', hello.views.affix, name='affix'),
    url(r'^carousel/$', hello.views.carousel, name='carousel'),
    url(r'^slideup_like_magic/$', hello.views.slideup_like_magic, name='slideup_like_magic'),
    url(r'^db', hello.views.db, name='db'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

`Django-1.9.2`

////// Additional //////

This is what I see when I move page from `http://bananaman.herokuapp.com/`.

[image]

And this is what I am supposed to see, for instance, `http://bananaman.herokuapp.com/slideup_like_magic`.[image]

Comment: That looks correct. What are you expecting or seeing "wrong" with the link?

Comment: @wobbily_col Thank you for your comment. For instance, when I click `responsive`, it moves to the page, but no image appears. But if I write `https://bananaman.herokuapp.com/bxslider` on Browser' bar and move, images appear. But the images don't appear if I visit the page from `https://bananaman.herokuapp.com/`.

Comment: seems like everything works for me, i see awesome cat there

Comment: @Anatoly Thank you for your comment. Really? If so, what's wrong with my laptop and smart phone? If you click `slideUp header` on `https://bananaman.herokuapp.com/` and does red header appear?

Comment: i check your html, how it could remain red if background slide to the top?

Comment: @Anatoly Sorry, not only red but also green. I uploaded photos. I should have done that when I posted this question. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't bothered to work through everything that is going on, but it looks like the issues you are experiencing are due to jQuery Mobile's link hijacking.  It doesn't look like you have your `data-*` attributes correct from one page to the next.

I think you should start by pulling out jQuery Mobile and make sure everything is working correctly.  Then add jQuery Mobile back in ensuring you have set up the page with the correct `data-role` attributes.

Comment: Ahh! Thank you so much. After I remove `jQuery Mobile` part, it became to work well. I wrote those `<a>` links after I added `jQuery Mobile`, so I couldn't trace what was wrong with the links. Thank you very much.